# How to store uploaded Files as Blob in mysql DB using JSF and PrimeFaces

Tags: mysql, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to upload a file and save it to mysql database. thus far, I am able to upload the file, print its detail. However, when I attempt to store it in the database via a helper class everything except for the ID become null. Can you take a look and let me know what I am missing? Also, let me know if you see anything that I should change/modify as code enhancement.

Uploading the file using JSF/Primefaces:

```
    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
     <p:fileUpload value="#{fileUploadView1.file}" mode="simple"/>
     <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false" actionListener="#{fileUploadView1.upload}" />
</h:form>
```

FileBean:

```
  @ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class FileUploadView1 {

    private InputStream input;
    private String fileName;
    private Long fileSize;
    private UploadedFile file;
    @Inject 
    private FileController1 fileController;

    public InputStream getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public Long getFileSize() {
        return fileSize;
    }

    public FileController1 getFileController() {
        return fileController;
    }

    public UploadedFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
        this.file = file;

        System.out.println("filesize " + file.getSize());
    }

    public void upload() throws IOException {

        if (file != null) {
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Succesful", file.getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);

            input = file.getInputstream();
            fileName = file.getFileName();
            fileSize = file.getSize();
            System.out.println("filesize3 " + file.getSize());
            fileController.uploadFile(file);

        }
    }
}
```

FileController:

```
   @ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class FileController1 {

    private FileDbUtil1 fileDbUtil;
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    public FileController1() throws Exception {

        fileDbUtil = FileDbUtil1.getInstance();
    }
    public String uploadFile(UploadedFile theFile) {

        logger.info("Uploading File: " + theFile);

        try {
            fileDbUtil.uploadFile(theFile);
               } catch (Exception exc) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error adding files", exc);

            addErrorMessage(exc);
            return null;
        }
        return "welcomePrimefaces";
    }



        private void addErrorMessage(Exception exc) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Error: " + exc.getMessage());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }



}
```

FileDbUtil File

```
 public static FileDbUtil1 getInstance() throws Exception {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new FileDbUtil1();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private FileDbUtil1() throws Exception {
        dataSource = getDataSource();
    }

    private DataSource getDataSource() throws NamingException {
        Context context = new InitialContext();

        DataSource theDataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup(jndiName);

        return theDataSource;
    }

    public void uploadFile(UploadedFile theFile) throws Exception {
        fileName = theFile.getFileName();
        input = theFile.getInputstream();


       Connection myConn = null;
        PreparedStatement myStmt = null;

        try {
            myConn = getConnection();

            String sql = "insert into  upload"
                    + "(name, file)"
                    + " values (?,?)";

            myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(sql);

            // set params
            myStmt.setString(1, fileName);
            myStmt.setBinaryStream(2, input);

            myStmt.executeUpdate();
        } finally {
            close(myConn, myStmt);
        }

    }



    private Connection getConnection() throws Exception {

        Connection theConn = dataSource.getConnection();

        return theConn;
    }

    private void close(Connection theConn, Statement theStmt) {
        close(theConn, theStmt, null);
    }

    private void close(Connection theConn, Statement theStmt, ResultSet theRs) {

        try {
            if (theRs != null) {
                theRs.close();
            }

            if (theStmt != null) {
                theStmt.close();
            }

            if (theConn != null) {
                theConn.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Stack Trace: Note that I am able to print the file size before calling the helper class

```
  Info:   filesize 3501
Info:   filesize3 3501
Warning:   java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:293)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.uploadfile.test.FileUploadView1.upload(FileUploadView1.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    ... 39 more

FATAL:   JSF1073: javax.faces.FacesException caught during processing of INVOKE_APPLICATION 5 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=java.lang.NullPointerException
FATAL:   java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:89)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:293)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.uploadfile.test.FileUploadView1.upload(FileUploadView1.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    ... 39 more
```

Comment: There are indeed a lot of mistakes, it basically needs a full rewrite (I suggest learning the basics based on a decent Java/JSF/JavaEE book). But the most important step, the instruction to save file in DB, is nowhere visible in code posted so far. Where are you calling `uploadFile()` in order to save the file in DB? I'd expect to see it being called inside the `fileUploadListener()`, immediately when the file comes in. But it's nowhere visible.

Comment: Updated the question, Note, that I am calling the FileController and passing the Uploaded file. can you take a look please?

Comment: Sorry, all those mistakes so far have got nothing to do with "store uploaded file in database". Moreover, you're right now basically asking "Why do I get a NullPointerException?" instead of "Why is variable X null?", pointing out the specific variable. This does not show a minimal understanding of basic Java. I recommend to crawl out the deep Java EE hole, leave the project for what it is and spend a few weeks carefully working through a decent Java SE book/tutorial.

Comment: Thanks I got it working. Even I didn't like it at first when you insisted that I need to figure out why instead of showing me how, but at least I learned something today.  Thanks gain for you help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.uploadfile.test.FileUploadView1.upload(FileUploadView1.java:68)

fileController isn't getting injected.

Use @Inject private FileController1 fileController.

BalusC is right on his comment.

Comment: Updated the question with your recommendation. I am still having null exception, please see the updated stack.